# (Android) unexpected match Pattern.compile("\\w+") with unicode letter

Tags: android, regex

The regular expression \ w character class in java.util.regex.Pattern on Android device produces results different from normal JVM.

Is there a way that \w match only [A-Za-z0-9_] on Android?

```
// kotlin
@Test
fun test() {

    // val pu = Pattern.compile("""\w+""",Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)
    // on Android: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported flags: 256

    fun matchOrNull(pattern:String,input:String):String?{
        // no UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS
        val m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(input)
        return if(m.find()) m.group(0) else null
    }

    assertEquals( null, matchOrNull("\\w+", "-"))
    assertEquals( "a", matchOrNull("\\w+", "a"))
    assertEquals( null, matchOrNull("\\w+", "あ"))
    // on Android: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<null> but was:<あ>
}
```

Comment: The thing is that on Android, ["*unicode character classes are always used*"](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern#constants_2). Use `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

Comment: my app allows users custom regexp and the data is things like url, hostname,  mentions. using \w is useability problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin, try this:

```
private val PASSWORD = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,256}")
private val MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 8

fun isValidPassword(password: String): Boolean {
   return password.length >= MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH && PASSWORD.matcher(password).matches()
}
```

This would validate the input string for Uppercase, lowercase, numeric and length > 8

Comment: I wrote a converter. https://github.com/tateisu/SubwayTooter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/jp/juggler/util/AsciiPattern.kt